# Running a Unit Test From Within A Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So my dilemma is that I'm trying to run a unit test from a controller. So, Im trying to make a system call from the controller using  `system("ruby -Itest ../../test/unit/user_model_test.rb > results.txt")`

However, I get

```
no such file to load -- test_helper (LoadError)
```

This is because I'm not running the command from my parent directory. Is there any way for ruby to make the call from the parent directory?

If I make a system call in a controller will it be run relative to the controller's location?

Comment: you can use require_relative '../test_helper' in your test. So that your test loads properly irrespective of the present working directory.

Answer (score 0):

The system call *will* execute from the Rails home directory. Simply execute the command you'd normally use to run a test, given your setup. E.g., `rake test:...` or `ruby test/unit/...`